# How we can setup build process for Multiple parent-child repos using jenkins

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, amazon-s3, bitbucket

Hi We are doing build setup for our project using jenkins, but we are facing issues for build automation as we are having parent-child repos.
Below is the scenario for Node build

We are having 
Common-repo
product-repo
service-repo

For creating service  build we need to have common and product repo to make it happen.

Can anyone help me for getting approaches for that.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Jenkins so that in the Configuration you may add the branch that you wish to build.
For eg: If you DEV , QA, and Prod branches and in build you want to run QA , then on the branch specifier write QA. This will build the app using code in QA branch.

Now for Prod, you may first merge QA to Prode from bitbuket and then run build in jenkins using Prod branch.

Comment: Actually here I am referring different repos not branches, We have different repos 
Common-Repo
Product-Repo
Service-Repo

For making build of Service-Repo, it needs product and common repo with it, Its like hierarchy,
Service repo refers Product repo and Product repo refers Common repo.

Flow is like Common --> Product --> Service 
We creates build for only service common and prod it use like libs.
Could you please help on this